# Pokemon GO- candy received for transfer

Tags: pokemon-go

Does the number of candies received from a transfer depend on the CP of the pokemon?

I have a Pidgey with 26 CP and caught a Pidgeotto with 14 CP. I am debating which to transfer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you get 1 candy per pokemon.

You'll catch a lot of pidgey's though. The best thing to do is to level up the CP on a smaller pokemon and then evolve it. The evolved pokemon will have a lot more CP than the pokemon it evolved from. You'll probably catch a higher CP pidgeotto at some point anyway.

Comment: This is incredibly confusing. What do you mean by "smaller pokemon"? Your answer seems to contradict itself. Why would you want to focus on evolving the pokemon, if you have a good chance of running into the evolved pokemon, anyway? That is quite a waste of candy..

Comment: From the context, "smaller Pokemon" should mean not evolved.

Comment: Not evolved is what I mean by smaller. Evolving pokemon gives you a lot of EXP as well. Apparently the best thing to do is to save up a lot of pokemon ready to evolve and use your lucky egg to power level. Evolving pokemon gives you a lot more exp than catching them.